# Custom animation for Activity

Tags: android, animation

I am developing an application in which I want a custom animation for an activity. More specifically, I have one fragment and an activity. When user clicks a item in the `ListView` in the fragment, user will be navigated to a new activity, where this activity should come from the bottom instead of default animation (fade in, I think). I have googled it, and found some solutions, but most of them are from one activity to another. So they use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity() ,x.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

Since i am calling the second activity from fragment, Android does not support this method (`overridePendingTransition`). Could anyone tell me any way to overcome this? In simple words, if user navigates from fragment to second activity, the second activity should come from the bottom instead of normal animation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In activity which will called with animation you should use this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_right_to_center, R.anim.anim_hold);
        setLayoutContent(R.layout.myactivtiy);
}
```

and if you want gone out with animation you should use this:

```
@Override
    public void onPause(){
        //todo detach from updater
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_hold, R.anim.anim_center_to_right);
    }
```

where R.anim.center_to_right :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="500"
       android:fromXDelta="100%"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:toXDelta="0%">
```

where R.anim.anim_hold :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="500"
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:toXDelta="0">
```